# How to select Multiple Radio Buttons in JSP

Tags: jsp, radio-button

How can I select More then one Radio Buttons on single JSP page?

```
<TR>
<TD align="left" colspan="2"><b>Execution Schedule Options :</b></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD width="23%" align="center">
<input type="radio" name="executionSchedule" name="now" value="now" checked="checked" />Now
</TD>
<TD width="33%" align="left">
      <input type="radio" name="executionSchedule" name="schedule" value="schedule" />Schedule
</TD>
</TR>
```

Here It is selecting Now as bydefault.

```
<TR>
<TD align="left" colspan="2"><b>Grid Execution Mode :</b></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD width="23%" align="center"><input type="radio"
name="executionSchedule" name="now" value="now"
checked="checked" />Manual Machine Selection</TD>
<TD width="33%" align="center"><input type="radio"
name="executionSchedule" name="schedule" value="schedule" />
Auto Machine Selection</TD>
</TR>
```

These both code of buttons are on same JSP page.
I have to select one button from Now/Schedule  and from Manual Machine/ Automation Machine, one button should be selected at the same time.
Inshort, Two buttons should be selected at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using same `names` for radio button it will act as mutually exclusive, ie only one can be selected at any one time. `Name` the radio button differently for one `executionSchedule` and for another `machineSelection` or something similar.